# Arrow label doesn't show up?

Tags: tikz-cd

I'm using the `to path` option for the first time in tikzcd, and run into the problem that the labels for my arrows do not show up:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
 & B \\
 A \arrow[ru,"c",to path={--(\tikztotarget.west)}]&
 \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

This just gives A and B, with an arrow, but I do not see the label?

Comment: Don't show snippets. Make a complete example, this makes it much easier to test your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `\tikztonodes` somewhere, to determine where nodes should be placed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
 & B \\
 A \arrow[ru,"c",to path={--(\tikztotarget.west) \tikztonodes}]&
 \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah oke thanks. Can I add multiple tikztnodes? And if so, which one will be used?

Comment: @user2520938 Just tried, you'll get duplicate labels if you have more than one `\tikztonodes`.